# jquery ajax / php poll database for changes

Tags: php, jquery

i am using thie jquery code to poll my database:

```
jQuery(function($){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.get( 'getrows.php', function(newRowCount){
      $('#rowcounter').html( newRowCount );
    });
  },5000); // 5000ms == 5 seconds
});
```

and display the results here:

```
<p>There are <span id='rowcounter'>xx</span> rows in the DB.</p>
```

but i am not sure what to put in the `getrows.php` file... does there need to be any html tags with an ID of `rowcounter` or `newRowCount`?

Answer (score 1):

After getting the number of rows in your database, just do:

`<?php echo $rowCount; //Or whatever value you want to show ?>`

That's all

Comment: hmm... i have this in getrows.php <?php
$pbx01_conn=mysql_connect("94.199.187.7:3306","integra","Yg4tgtYoAeat");
mysql_select_db("voipnow",$pbx01_conn);

$sql="SELECT * from extension_rule where id = '1580' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$pbx01_conn);
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
echo $result["status"];
?> but its just displaying There are xx rows in the DB.

Comment: try to execute `getrows.php` on a different browser page. It's possible your query returned no results.

Comment: the path was incorrect :) i am trying this now: if($result["status"] == '1')
{
 echo 'on';
}
elseif($result["status"] == '0')
{
 echo 'off';
} but its not returning anything but if i change it to just echo 'hello'; is displays

Comment: It seems your Javascript doesn't work as excpected: your "xx" isn't erased.
Anyways, concerning your last comment: could you just try a `echo $result["status"];`?

Comment: got it :) working fine now. is there anyway to change it so it doesnt check another page (getrows.php) - can it check some PHP code on the same page?

Comment: i will do - one more thing above though :)

Comment: I guess you're thinking of a way to take out the round trip to the server. Unfortunately, all AJAX requests would be made to a Server and making the Ajax request to "the same page" (as you put it) would mean the client requests for a copy of your current page every 5 seconds(or at whatever interval you poll runs)

Comment: To do that though, say your page is called `pollorigin.php`, then you could make your AJAX request to `pollorigin.php?ajax=1`; Doing this, you can then check `if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) { /* Perform Ajax Ops */ exit(); } else { /* Regular Page Content Here */}`

Answer (score 0):

You're simply requesting `getrows.php` and expecting a response from it.

You can do anything there, as long as you echo something. Like:

```
<?php

     echo rand(1,10);

?>
```

When jQuery requests this page, PHP will generate a random number, and jQuery will append it to HTML.

Basically, you can respond anything there. jQuery doesn't care what you're responding.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that code, all the PHP file needs to do is emit a number.  You'd have normal data-access code like you would anywhere else, then just:

```
echo $someValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery intelligently guesses](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) the type of data returned by your php script (definable in your php request's script with ContentType).

A simple php script would return HTML/Text data, so you just have to "echo" your number in your PHP script. Then your `newRowCount` JS value will contain your PHP-echoed number.